# Global security configuration in OpenSAML 3.0+

Tags: java, opensaml

I'm upgrading OpenSAML in a Java 8 project from v 2.6.1 to 3.3.1
A lot of code compilation errors are fixable pretty easy but I'm stuck at a certain point.

If we use a signing Algorithm we had previously following code:

```
KeyPair signingKeyPair = parseKeyPair(properties.getProperty("signingKey"), properties.getProperty("signingKeyPassword"));
signingCredential = createCredential(signingKeyPair, serviceProviderID, UsageType.SIGNING);
if (properties.getProperty("signingAlgorithm") != null) {
    SecurityConfiguration securityConfiguration = Configuration.getGlobalSecurityConfiguration();
    if (securityConfiguration instanceof BasicSecurityConfiguration && "RSA".equals(signingCredential.getPublicKey().getAlgorithm())) {
               ((BasicSecurityConfiguration) securityConfiguration).registerSignatureAlgorithmURI("RSA", properties.getProperty("signingAlgorithm"));
    }
}
```

In OpenSAML 3.0+ the line Configuration.getGlobalSecurityConfiguration(); doesn't compile anymore. How do I get the global security configuration in OpenSAML 3.0+?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I have not used these security configuration classes before, but I have some experience upgrading from OpenSAML 2.x to 3.x and digging around in the OpenSAML docs and source to find my way.*

I hope this will get you started:

```
// initializes the various security configurations
GlobalSecurityConfigurationInitializer.init();

// fetches the various security configurations
DecryptionConfiguration dc = SecurityConfigurationSupport.getGlobalDecryptionConfiguration();
EncryptionConfiguration ec = SecurityConfigurationSupport.getGlobalEncryptionConfiguration();
SignatureSigningConfiguration ssc = SecurityConfigurationSupport.getGlobalSignatureSigningConfiguration();
SignatureValidationConfiguration svc = SecurityConfigurationSupport.getGlobalSignatureValidationConfiguration();
```

I'm not sure which of those configurations holds the functionality you need, but here are the Javadocs with some additional detail:

- [DecryptionConfiguration](https://build.shibboleth.net/nexus/content/sites/site/java-opensaml/3.2.0/apidocs/org/opensaml/xmlsec/DecryptionConfiguration.html) / [BasicDecryptionConfiguration](https://build.shibboleth.net/nexus/content/sites/site/java-opensaml/3.2.0/apidocs/org/opensaml/xmlsec/impl/BasicDecryptionConfiguration.html)
- [EncryptionConfiguration](https://build.shibboleth.net/nexus/content/sites/site/java-opensaml/3.2.0/apidocs/org/opensaml/xmlsec/EncryptionConfiguration.html) / [BasicEncryptionConfiguration](https://build.shibboleth.net/nexus/content/sites/site/java-opensaml/3.2.0/apidocs/org/opensaml/xmlsec/impl/BasicEncryptionConfiguration.html)
- [SignatureSigningConfiguration](https://build.shibboleth.net/nexus/content/sites/site/java-opensaml/3.2.0/apidocs/org/opensaml/xmlsec/SignatureSigningConfiguration.html) / [BasicSignatureSigningConfiguration](https://build.shibboleth.net/nexus/content/sites/site/java-opensaml/3.2.0/apidocs/org/opensaml/xmlsec/impl/BasicSignatureSigningConfiguration.html)
- [SignatureValidationConfiguration](https://build.shibboleth.net/nexus/content/sites/site/java-opensaml/3.2.0/apidocs/org/opensaml/xmlsec/SignatureValidationConfiguration.html) / [BasicSignatureValidationConfiguration](https://build.shibboleth.net/nexus/content/sites/site/java-opensaml/3.2.0/apidocs/org/opensaml/xmlsec/impl/BasicSignatureValidationConfiguration.html)

You can also [check out the OpenSAML source](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/DEV/Source+Code+Access#SourceCodeAccess-CurrentJavaRepositories); specifically, the `DefaultSecurityConfigurationBootstrap` class is where a lot of this gets set up.